# Is it possible to convert a str to an int using csv.DictReader?

Tags: python, csv

I'm reading in a csv and a text file using `csv.DictReader` and my values become strings.
I can't figure out how to convert them to integers, the code is as follows:

```py
    with open(full_path_csv, 'r') as csv_file:
    with open(full_path_conf, 'r') as text_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, fieldnames=("name", "count"))
        text_reader = csv.DictReader(text_file, fieldnames=("name", "alarm_limit", "err_limit"), delimiter=";")
```

Is there an easy way to convert the `"count" & "alarm_limit" + "err_limit"` to int values with an iteration that I can also use compare the values?

Comment: Have you tried the `int()` function? Also your values don't "become" strings, CSV files are untyped, they only contain strings.

Comment: Like this? int(csv_row["count"]) in a loop over both files?

Comment: Something along those lines yes, or by wrapping your readers in a `map`.

Comment: Should've figured that out by myself haha, it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert strings to integers using `integer_value = int("string")`.

E.g.: `k = int("42")`

Answer (score 0):

If you use Pandas library it can recognize the columns types for you as numbers or dates etc.

But that might be too heavy and advanced for basic CSV cases.

So you'll just have to convert each value to an integer the old fashioned way.

PS You don't have to specify fieldnames when *reading* a CSV, it is recognized for you.